# Does QT Creator have a split file view?

Tags: qt-creator

I am rather new to QT Creator and I'm wondering if there is a feature that allows a side by side file view within a single window?

Form past experience in other IDEs (CLion, VSCode, etc) right clicking on the file tab brings up the option to split multiple files, although this does not seem to be the case in QT Creator.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-coding-navigating.html

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is a button to do that on the top right just after the Line and Column numbers.
you can split vertically or horizontally as many times as you want.
[image: here is a snapshot]

You've also the 2 options in the `Window` menu:

- Split Ctrl+E,2
- Split Side by Side Ctrl+E,3

For the shortcut, first do Ctrl+E, release it and straight after press the number.